# How to send "int" value in to from, that blocking any string sing

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have next problem: When I try to send value(phone number) using:

```
 elem.sendKeys("6547898");
```

I can't do it because form work only with integer.
I know that I can use:

```
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_9);
```

(and I have used it and it worked) but may be someone know how to do it without use `Robot()`? `Robot` is not comfortable.

Thank you!

Comment: Is it a `WebElement`? Then you can send multiple keys with `WebElement.sendKeys("abacaba")`.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg I know but it's doesn't send an element. In rezalt i just have a empty field!

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg it's send element(Im sorry) but form think that it's type of String!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `elem` is a `WebElement`, you can use:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;

...

elem.sendKey(Keys.NUMPAD9);
```

---

**EDIT**

Since this did not work, an alternative to the Robot would be to run a JavaScript snippet through your `WebDriver` instance to change the field's value to what you want. It would be something like:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("$('#phone').prop('value', '+3806547898');");
```

Comment: Can you elaborate further on how the form field will only accept integers? If you really must avoid using a Robot, which I'd totally understand, we could run a JavaScript snippet through the `WebDriver` to change the field value to what we want. I edited my answer.

Comment: <input class="error" autocomplete="off" id="phone" name="phone" value="+380" maxlength="13" type="text"> - it's a html code of form, when I using  sendKeys(Keys.NUMPAD9) field just red. I used debug and saw that numbers didn't write.

Comment: I don't see how this html code is only accepting integers. I guess there is some JavaScript behind. Have you tried the other strategy?

Comment: Ok i try to do it but I have WebDriverException. Other strategy - what the strategy?

Comment: I meant this strategy, with the JavaScript snippet. What is the `WebDriverException` message?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: $(...) is null
Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:16:47'

Comment: thank you bro I change javascript for it ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('phone').value = '+380635488938';"); and it work

Comment: You're welcome. if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and upvoting it by clicking the check-mark and the up arrow. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

sendKeys() does not accept Integer as a parameter therefore you need to convert the integer to a string then use it in the sendKeys command.

Example

```
int intPeriod= (int)Double.parseDouble(period);
element.sendKeys(String.valueOf(intPeriod));
```